# Diagonal green squares on screen

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have an XPS-15 7590 running 18.04 and I have both the Intel & NVIDIA graphics card.  The specs are basically: i9 processor, NVIDIA GTX 1650 GPU, and 4K OLED. I've been trying to work on the NVIDIA & Intel drivers (installed Nvidia proprietary and iwlwifi Intel driver) through the Software & Updates manager and tried to install simulators like CARLA, Lgsvl and so on.  I tried to switch to the NVIDIA graphics card with this command (because Nvidia X server settings didn't work):

`sudo prime-select nvidia`

After a reboot, I am welcomed with a screen overlaid by repeating artifacts:

[image: Camera picture of artifacts]

I tried running the same command `sudo prime-select intel` but the situation persists.  Now when I look at Nvidia X Server settings manager (it decided to work again for some reason), Intel is selected so I'm definitely not on the Nvidia GPU.

This isn't the only screen issue I'm having. Apps like Android Messages shows vertical screen ripping as you can see below.

[image]

Although I don't mind doing a fresh install, I don't think that is necessary as I believe there are existing solutions to this problem.  Not only that but a fresh install is pretty much pointless since this problem will start once again when I install my necessary software.

FOLLOW-UP:

A clean reinstall of 18.04 solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar issue when upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Similar case when using Nvidia-prime, but with "On Demand" profile.
So in fact still using the Intel graphic card for the desktop.

Solution was to remove the xserver-xorg-video-intel driver which is [discouraged for hardware from 2007 and newer. Better to uninstall this driver and let the system use its builtin modesetting driver instead.](https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/xserver-xorg-video-intel)

This can be done by the following command:

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I found this solution here:
[Ubuntu 20.04 graphics driver problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238156/ubuntu-20-04-graphics-driver-problem)

It's probably too late for the initial problem, but this may help other people.