# Ubuntu 20.04 graphics driver problem

Tags: fonts, intel-graphics, 20.04, visual-artifacts, i915

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04, and now I have a problem with my graphics rendering (strange squares on background and font problems). I use the i915 driver. Graphics card: Skylake GT2 HD Graphics 520. I tried to reinstall GNOME shell and Xorg server. Nothing helped. Also Chrome browser breaks on most of pages.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Given the output, do you have a way to try with another graphics adapter on this same machine? I am wondering, because Chrome uses all kinds of GPU acceleration. And so issues with the graphics card (or the respective driver) would be expected to cause the issues you describe.

Comment: unfortunately I can’t use another video card, this is a laptop.

Comment: @Veniamin I feared as much. You may want to also look at answers to [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1238080/11316) where the OP seems to experience surprisingly similar symptoms.

Comment: I look at upgrade log and find out: file /etc/X11/xorg.conf was missing. Probably I deleted it earlier. I restore this file with sudo X -configure and copy new file to /etc/X11/xorg.conf. But problem exists

Comment: I tried to install latest video drivers from ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers and install kernel 5.4.0-28 intead of 5.4.0-29. It did not help.

Comment: I've yet to try @proamar's solution (see his answer), but I noticed, I can get rid of the artifacts by restarting GNOME (`Alt` + `F2` then `r`). Note: This only works for the current session, upon the next reboot the artifacts are back.

Answer (score 11):

I had the similar problem and on my research found that it's intel new graphic update problem. I was able to solve my issue by issuing following commands on my terminal.

`sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel`

After issuing the command, it is recommended that you restart your pc but logout and log back in may also work fine. I hope this will be able to solve your problem. If you face any issue please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! It had solved my problem! Chrome also stopped crashing.

Comment: You are always welcome!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me too! Only needed to logout and back in, no restart needed.

Comment: This answer solve the issue by uninstalling the 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' driver, which is in fact recommanded when using Intel graphic cards newer than 2007:
https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/xserver-xorg-video-intel

Seems you can safely uninstall this driver if your hardware is new enough.